# How to make regex expression starting with a sequence and ending with }

Tags: android, regex, string, replace

I a trying to replace a character pattern from string but am not able to make it despite huge efforts. This is the string:

```
{
trainNo: "12026",
startDate: "09 Apr 2014",
trainName: "SC-PUNE SHATABDI",
trnName:function(){return _LANG=="en-us"?"SC-PUNE SHATABDI":"&#2360;&#2367;&#2325;&#2306;&#2342;&#2352;&#2366;&#2348;&#2366;&#2342; &#2346;&#2369;&#2339;&#2375; &#2358;&#2340;&#2366;&#2348;&#2381;&#2342;&#2368;"},
trainSrc: "SC",
trainDstn: "PUNE",
runsOn: "NA",
schArr: "Source",
schDep: "14:45, 09 Apr",
schHalt: "Source",
actArr: "Source",
delayArr: "RIGHT TIME",
actDep: "14:45, 09 Apr",
delayDep: "RIGHT TIME",
actHalt: "Source",
trainType: "SHT"
} ,
```

I would like to replace this pattern :

```
trnName:function(){return _LANG=="en-us"?"SC-PUNE SHATABDI":"&#2360;&#2367;&#2325;&#2306;&#2342;&#2352;&#2366;&#2348;&#2366;&#2342; &#2346;&#2369;&#2339;&#2375; &#2358;&#2340;&#2366;&#2348;&#2381;&#2342;&#2368;"},
```

I have tried this pattern but of no avail:

```
data = data.replaceAll("\\{.*?\\}", "");
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The pattern is "trnName:function(){ },"

Comment: I would like to remove all occurrences of this pattern from the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
data = data.replaceAll("trnName:function\\(\\)\\{[^{}]*\\},\\s*", "");
```

It will match all of the string you said you want to match:

```
trnName:function(){return _LANG=="en-us"?"SC-PUNE SHATABDI":"&#2360;&#2367;&#2325;&#2306;&#2342;&#2352;&#2366;&#2348;&#2366;&#2342; &#2346;&#2369;&#2339;&#2375; &#2358;&#2340;&#2366;&#2348;&#2381;&#2342;&#2368;"},
```

...including the trailing comma (`,`) and the linefeed following it.

---

The problem with [aelor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22964262/20938) is that it's just a raw regex.  You have to double-escape it for use in a Java string literal.  (I also escaped the braces, which might not be necessary in Android, whose regex flavor is slightly different from Java's.)

Answer (score 1):

search

```
\(trnName:function\(\)){.*}
```

and replace with

```
\1
```

Comment: Getting this error: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: @user1726619 have you tried escaping the parens like this : `\(trnName:function\(\)){.*}`

Comment: Getting exception: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Error in {min,max} interval near index 24:
 (trnName:function\(\)){.*}

Comment: This is the code : mResponseData = mResponseData.replaceAll("\\(trnName:function\\(\\)){.*}", "");

Comment: Did you try to escape the '}' character as well? like this `\{` and `\}` or may be `\\{` or `\\}`

Comment: The exception is gone. But it is still not working. The same sequence is not getting replaced with ""

Comment: did you use a `\{` or a `\\{` try using `\{` only

Comment: hopefully it will start working with `\{` just do a final try

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving your time sir. Thanks